# Python bs4: extract/select parts of html divs

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

could anyone help me with the extraction of the 'name' as well as the 'description':

```
</div>, <div class="bubble-description">
<p><b>name</b><br/>
                    description 
                    </p>
```

I know how to extract the name. But the description part is a bit cumbersome. Here is my code:

```
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

content = soup.select('div.bubble-description')

name = [x.select('p')[0].contents[0].text for x in content]
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<div class="bubble-description">
<p>
    <b>name</b>
    <br/>
    description 
</p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

desc = soup.select_one(".bubble-description")

name = desc.b.text.strip()
desc = desc.br.find_next(text=True).strip()
print(name)
print(desc)
```

Prints:

```
name
description
```

---

Or using unique separator, e.g. `|`:

```py
desc = soup.select_one(".bubble-description")

n, d = desc.get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|")
print(n)
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
name
description
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my problem. I opted for the first part.